# Why the "q_ptr" pointer is assigned to "this" pointer of QObject?

Tags: qt

Like the title,why the "q_ptr" pointer is assigned to "this" pointer of QObject? in source code.

```
QObject::QObject(QObjectPrivate &dd, QObject *parent)
: d_ptr(&dd)
{
>>Q_D(QObject);
>>d_ptr->q_ptr = this;/*question*/
.......
```

Then,when use `Q_Q()` macro in source code like blow:

```
Q_Q(QWidget)
```

It will return the q pointer handled by the function q_fun():

```
QWidget*q_func() {return static_cast<QWidget*>(q_ptr);}
```

As all we know,`static_cast`is not safe when cast from parent to child.

I am very frustrated about `/*question*/` ,can any guy tell me the secret?Thanks!

Comment: Semantic note: `this` is being assigned to `q_ptr`, not the other way around. `a = b;`: value of b is assigned to a (i.e. a takes on the value of b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d_ptr->q_ptr = this;/*question*/
```

This is where the private implementation object ([PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer)) is told about the object it is working for/with (the non-private `QObject`). [Here's a good link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160506000653/http://zchydem.enume.net/2010/01/19/qt-howto-private-classes-and-d-pointers/) for info about Qt and `d pointer`s (d_ptr).

`Q_Q` macro returns the pointer to the `QObject`, so you can emit signals from it (among other things). As for the `static_cast` bit, that is safe because the macro is defined differently for each class created by the `Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE` and `Q_DECLARE_PUBLIC` macros: the result being, `static_cast` is always casting to the correct type.  Again, I recommend reading the link.

Comment: I have read this link before and I will read it again,thank you!

Comment: I found that many articles about q pointer always describe q_ptr's assignment like following: MyObjectPrivate(MyObject * parent):q_ptr( parent ) {} .This is so easy for all guys to understand the q_ptr now point to public class MyObject.however ,how to understand the Qt's way :d_ptr->q_ptr = this.The "this" always point to QObject but not the public class of the private class d_ptr pointing to.

Comment: If you notice in the constructor of QObject that you posted, the QObjectPrivate is passed by reference as an argument. This indicates that the private object was constructed first, so the syntax you wish for (in your comment) doesn't work - there is no public QObject to pass the private's constructor! So, the private object is constructed first, and when the public object is constructed, it gives a pointer to itself to the private one.  If you can include a link to where exactly you got the code you posted about, I can look further.

Comment: this question I found is in Qt4.7.3(4) source code ,you can find them everywhere.Now, I found that the functions invoked by q_ptr are normal funtions instead of virtual funtions.So I guess that,when q_ptr is static_cast to a "type",it will call the type's funtions rather than parent's.